# Wi-Fi Driver on Dell N4050?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, drivers, bluetooth, dell-inspiron

When i check my device manager i have **Dell Wireless 1702 802.11 b/g/n, BT3.0+HS Driver** but i have currently installed **Dell Wireless 1703 802.11b/g/n, Bluetooth 4.0 + HS Driver** and now i am thinking to upgrade to **Dell Wireless 1704 WiFi + Bluetooth Driver** ? My question here is am I being stupid here for installing a different driver than i am supposed to ? What kinds of problems will I face if i do so ? Will it affect my performance or internet speed ? Please help me ASAP with some good clarifications ! Thank you.

My system specs are as :

**System** : *Windows 7 - 64 BIT*
**Processor** : *Intel Celeron 1.6 GHZ [Dual Core]*
**Video Card** : *around 700 MB*
**RAM** : *2 GB*

Comment: Does the wireless work?  If so why would you even need to install a newer driver?  If it isn't broken don't fix it.

Comment: yes it does work perfectly , I just want better performance over the Wi-Fi :)

Comment: What will happen depends on the exact driver and hardware.  It could work better, or worse, or not work at all.

Comment: It also depends on why the driver was updated. It may or may not improve anything for you. They don't always update drivers specifically to improve performance, as much as fix known issues.

Comment: uhh ? so you guys mean i should let it be ? i downgraderd my driver to 1702 according to my hardware id !